# RegEx to search for all CSS lines containing a color code | Sublime Text 3

Tags: css, regex, sublimetext3

I have a large file consisting of ~4,000 lines of CSS within Sublime Text. I'd like to write a RegEx to search the file for all CSS rules containing a specific color code (which is #48535B,) so I can copy each of the corresponding CSS rules out into another file, and then delete them from the original file. What would be a good RegEx to accomplish this?

So for example, I have CSS rules formatted like so:

```
a {
    color:#000;
    text-decoration:none
}
a:hover,a:focus {
    color:#999;
    text-decoration:underline
}

.model-selector-parallax .carousel-prev,
.model-selector-parallax .carousel-next,
.ddc-btn-primary,
.showroom-detail .hproduct .view-link,
.showroom-detail .callout .callout-button,
.pricing .ePrice .ddc-btn, .pricing .eprice-button,
.pricing .ddc-btn[data-eprice],
.mycars-favorites .hproduct .pricing .make-an-offer,
.locations-proximity {
        outline:thin dotted #48535B !important;
        outline:5px auto -webkit-focus-ring-color;
        outline-offset:-2px
    }

img {
    vertical-align:middle
}
.img-responsive {
    display:block;
    max-width:100%;
    height:auto
}
.img-rounded {
    border-radius:0px
}`
```

I'd like the RegEx to find the entire rule which contains "#48535B", and highlight it from the beginning of the rule to the close `}` bracket. So in this case, it would find and highlight (including all of the comma separated classes, even if they're on different lines):

```
.model-selector-parallax .carousel-prev,
.model-selector-parallax .carousel-next,
.ddc-btn-primary,
.showroom-detail .hproduct .view-link,
.showroom-detail .callout .callout-button,
.pricing .ePrice .ddc-btn, .pricing .eprice-button,
.pricing .ddc-btn[data-eprice],
.mycars-favorites .hproduct .pricing .make-an-offer,
.locations-proximity {
        outline:thin dotted #48535B !important;
        outline:5px auto -webkit-focus-ring-color;
        outline-offset:-2px
    }
```

At which point, I can copy all the results and paste them into a separate file.

Also, a RegEx to avoid matching a certain color code. So for example, if we're trying to avoid matching `48535B` and we have:

```
.navbar-default {
  -webkit-box-shadow:rgba(0,0,0,0.15) 0px 10px 10px;
  -moz-box-shadow:rgba(0,0,0,0.15) 0px 10px 10px;
  box-shadow:rgba(0,0,0,0.15) 0px 10px 10px;
  border-top:solid #f2f2f2;
  border-bottom:solid #48535B !important;
  border-width:2px 0 1px
}
```

The RegEx would find and highlight:

```
.ddc-navbar-default {
  -webkit-box-shadow:rgba(0,0,0,0.15) 0px 10px 10px;
  -moz-box-shadow:rgba(0,0,0,0.15) 0px 10px 10px;
  box-shadow:rgba(0,0,0,0.15) 0px 10px 10px;
  border-top:solid #f2f2f2;
  border-width:2px 0 1px
}
```

Meaning that it finds and highlights everything but the line that contains `48535B`, including comma separated classes on different lines.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you very much!

Comment: And you have tried what so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this one an it seems to work:

```
[^{\n]+\{[^}]+#[0-9a-f]{6}[^}]+\}
```

I'm not an expert on regular expressions, though. I hope it works for you

For comma-separated multi-line rules, this one seems to work for me:

```
^[^{}]+\{[^}]+#[0-9a-f]{6}[^}]+\}
```

For avoiding matching certain color `code`:

```
^[^{}]+\{[^}]+#(?!code)[0-9a-f]{6}[^}]+\}
```

For example, this will not match `ffffff`:

```
^[^{}]+\{[^}]+#(?!ffffff)[0-9a-f]{6}[^}]+\}
```

Comment: This worked, thank you! However, this only appears to work for single line rules, and not rules containing comma separated classes with classes on different lines. My apologies, I should have specified that this needed to function as such. How would we adjust the RegEx to include comma separated classes with classes on different lines? I edited my original question to include an example. Thank you!

Comment: One more question: how would I search for and highlight any CSS rule that DOESN'T contain the specified color code (including comma separated rules, only searching within the `{ }` brackets)?

Comment: You're welcome. I updated my answer to avoid matching certain color code. I didn't understand that part about the brackets, though

Comment: I just updated my question to include an example of what I mean. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: I don't think that's possible with any kind of search, but you could copy the rules with the color codes and then use a find/replace to remove the lines with the color